# How to use aerospike as cache in Spring boot data jpa project with mysql and pgsql as datasources?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, aerospike

We have implemented our application in spring boot + spring data jpa + mysql&pgsql as databases. Can we use aerospike as cache only for my application ? There is no proper documentation or sample project available for reference.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options to use Aerospike as a cache tier with Spring Boot:

1. Use Spring Data Aerospike with Spring Cache features backed by Aerospike, with this you won't need to write the cache implementation logic, alternatively you can use annotation such as @Cacheable, CachePut and @CacheEvict that will be responsible for the actual implementation behind the scenes, here is a blog post about it: https://medium.com/aerospike-developer-blog/caching-with-spring-boot-and-aerospike-17b91267d6c
2. Use Spring Data Aerospike to write your own cache implementation logic (try to search a record in Aerospike and if not found go to MySQL/PostgreSQL, write back to Aerospike etc...), you can use AerospikeRepository to reduce a lot of boilerplate code it won't be as easy as to use the first option but it will be more flexible.

I suggest to go to Spring Data Aerospike GitHub repository, go through the README and documentation and possibly blog posts/examples that suit your requirement: https://github.com/aerospike/spring-data-aerospike